# Email server Catch All, multiple unknown domains which redirect email via MX records

Tags: devops, postfix-mta, system-administration, mail-server, dovecot

I want to setup an email server with a catch-all strategy.

If somebody is sending emails to `xxx@mydomain.com` ---> redirect it to `allmails@mydomain.com` [ALREADY DONE]

If somebody has a domain  `hisdomain.com` and creates an MX record in his DNS provider pointing to ==> `mydomain.com`, I want everything that is sent to `xxx@hisdomain.com` to have it straightly to `allmails@mydomain.com` [TRYING TO DO]

`mydomain.com` --> Is my domain and we know it.

`hisdomain.com` -> Could be anything, any domain that has configured MX records to redirect email to `mydomain.com`

---

Suggest me any solution I can use to build my own email server with the catch-all strategy as above.

Then, I want to use IMAP to read `allmails@mydomain.com` via Node.js

Comment: What Mailserver software are you using?

Comment: @DarrenStreet I am using this repo
https://github.com/htmlgraphic/Mail-Server

to configure my mail server with Docker. 
So, I am using the DOVECOT IMAP Server from there.